# Standard JSON format for PHP

Tags: php, json

I am storing data in JSON files with array of JSON objects.

Right Now I am doing like

```
[{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}]
```

Is this universally accepted. ? If so which Tech Lead company supports this format .

Comment: JSON is universal data format. So it is supported. In your case, however, json is __incorrect__ as it uses single quotes. Correct json uses __double__ quotes. More info on [json.org](http://json.org).

Comment: Okay ... let me correct that .. And thanks for opening the eyes of beginner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a reason for wrapping your main values in `[]`? Are you intending to structure it as the following `[{'key1':'value1','key2':'value2'.....},{'keyN':'valueN','keyN':'valueN'}.....]` or similar? If not then using `[]` is pretty pointless.

Comment: The reason is : I have read the file and store it in array and access each objects one by one ... Does it make sense here ???

Comment: So how I've described it then? If not then structuing it as -

`{'object1': {'key1':'value1','key2':'value2'}, 'object2' {'key1':'value1','key2':'value2'}}`

Would probably work better for you.

Comment: If we follow this convention, is it possible to iterate over the objects. I think it's not possible @Raffers

Comment: Yes, it would be possible. You would first iterate over the array of the objects, then you would iterate over the values within the object. I assume you're passing to some JS?